# Restore QT application to default language?

Tags: qt

Default language of my application is English. I created a translation to another language and that works just fine.

However, I did not find any easy way to reset app to the default language. I could create .ts file for the default language as well, but that seems a bit awkward (and I do not seem to find any automatic way in linguist that would automatically generate ts file of the default language).

So how can I reset my app to the default language?

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave text untranslated in ts file, it will appear untranslated. so the simplest way is to add translation file for the default language but leave it empty.

There is also flag -pluralonly for lupdate, which will skip all translations exept plural forms, which would be useful to translate even in default language.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I only added file name for the default language to the pro file. It did not even require that file needs to exist. Thank you very much :)